# python: How to query an email json indexed into elasticsearch using date

Tags: python, json, date, elasticsearch

I indexed a set of emails into `Elasticsearch`. Now I'd like to query this set to retrieve some email based on the `date` header. The `date` format is the following:

`EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z (z)`

where `EEE` stands for the name of the day (ex. `Thu`), `Z` stands for time zone offset (ex. `-0800`) and `(z)` stands for time zone (ex. `PST`).

This is a very long string to put into a query and very easy to fail when you're trying to type in.
So my idea (whether it's possible) should be to query the set of emails by simply insert a string like the following one:

`12 07 2017`

so considering just the very actual date and getting rid of the other parts of the date. 
Is it possible doing that using `python` and `elasticsearch-dsl`?

Comment: how are you storing the date field - e.g. are you using a date field in Elasticsearch or a text field?

Comment: I'm using date field format

Comment: in that case the date will be stored as an integer, the number of milliseconds in UTC since 1970 (epoch format). You don't need to match the exitsing format. Just use a date range format as per here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#ranges-on-dates